# How to check columns value Exists in other table Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exists

I have two tables :

```
tblPerson :
-------------------
ID|Name|Family|JobName(string)
-------------------


tblJob:
-------------------
Id|JobName(string)
-------------------
```

I wanna run this query as Entity Framework ,

```
Select * From tblJob
   Where  JobName NOT EXIST IN (Select JobName From tblPerson)
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried by including a code sample.

Comment: Context.Job.Where(_job=>!_job.JobName.Contians(Context.Person.Select(_person=>_person.JobName));, I'm confused.please help me.I can't check a column (string) exists in other table

Comment: how is the entity framework model composed? is there a FK between tables?

Comment: Perhaps this will be a good place to start https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If there's a FK modeled in the context you can do this:

```
Context.Job.Where(job => !job.Person.Any());
```

otherwise

```
Context.Job.Where(job => !Context.Person.Any(p => p.JobName == job.JobName));
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, it's useful.